# Why wont my Redux & React JSX accept my IF statement even when *outside* of my render?

Tags: reactjs, redux

newbie here - desperately trying to get a logged-in section to say "Logged In" or "Logged Out" instead of the bool `true` or `false`.

I can get it `console.log` (see `myLoginStatus` which is the status passed in as props) - and it does this fine.

And i can get an H1 tag to show true or false fine too (though that's not coded here).

But to get an `if` or `ternary` statement that governs if `myLoginStatus` is `true` then the H1 to display "logged in" is drawing blanks...

NOTE:
I know if/else statements aren't supposed to work in JSX, but i read in 
[Dev Nacho's blog](http://devnacho.com/2016/02/15/different-ways-to-add-if-else-statements-in-JSX/) that you can get round this by putting it before the `render()` ?

Can anyone give me a pointer?

LAYOUT

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {

renderUserMessage() {
  let myLoginStatus = this.props.loginStatus;
  console.log('Login Status: ', myLoginStatus);
  if (myLoginStatus = 'true') {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>You are logged IN</h1>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>You are logged OUT</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


  render() {

    return (
      <div>

        <h1>Login Status:  {this.renderUserMessage()}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.toggleLogin()}>CLICK ME</button>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two equal signs `==` to compare values:

Perhaps `if (myLoginStatus = 'true')` should be `if (myLoginStatus == 'true')` or just `if (myLoginStatus)`?

Comment: Thanks @LarsBlumberg you were bang-on. I forgot i'd run a String() method on it in my redux render, because it was a bool. So as soon as i popped the dbl-equals/== on it and wrapped the speech marks round it - boom we're on our way. Many thanks!